# RMI binding fails with "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmitest.IRemote"

Tags: java, rmi

I have an issue binding a remote object to the RMI registry. I've reduced my code to a very simple example that works fine when I test it on my computer (Windows 10). But if I start it on another computer (Windows 7), when  `registry.bind(id, remoteObject);` gets called, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
rmitest.IRemote (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

I shouldn't need a SecurityManager since all class files are in the jar and I don't want to use the dynamic code loading feature.

Why does it try to load a security manager and why can't it find one even if I define one? What could be the reason that it works on one machine but not another? I think the code is ok and it must some configuration issue, but I'm not sure what exactly is configured wrong.

Here is the remote interface and remote object implementation, which I exported as runnable Jar in Eclipse as `rmitest.jar`.

```
public interface IRemote extends Remote {
    void foo() throws RemoteException;
}
```

```
public class RemoteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IRemote {

    private static Registry     registry;

    public RemoteImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // already created
        }
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
        registry.bind(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), new RemoteImpl());
        System.out.println("Binding successful");
    }

    @Override
    public void foo() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

Here is the full stack trace, it throws in the line where `registry.bind` gets called and is exactly the same when running with either of the following commands:
`java -jar rmitest.jar` or
`java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=policy -jar rmitest.jar`

It's quite strange that apparently in both cases a security manager is required but even in the second case it can't find one.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmitest.IRemote (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:379)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at rmitest.RemoteImpl.main(RemoteImpl.java:29)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmitest.IRemote (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmitest.IRemote (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
```

Here is the policy file, which should allow everything:

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Comment: It *doesn't* 'try to load a security manager', and there is nothing here that suggests otherwise. It tries to load your *class*, and doesn't find it. Don't jump to conclusions.

Comment: @EJP What I meant to say was "expects a security manager to be present", as I interpret the exeption message to suggest that a missing security manager is the reason why the class can't be loaded.

Comment: Well it doesn't mean either of those things. It is a *note* that the security manager isn't running. Not the reason.

Comment: And what you *are* failing with is `ClassNotFoundException: rmitest.IRemote`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was 'some other Java process' *that was providing its own Registry,* which didn't have access to your CLASSPATH. You would have found that if you had something better than an empty `catch` block for `createRegistry()`.

Comment: Yeah an empty catch block is an atrocity that I shouldn't have done - but I replicated the issue and logged the exception and it's always exactly the same `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind`, no matter if the registry has access to the classpath or not.

Comment: Anyway, it sounds to me that I should to avoid using `createRegistry` at the default port, if I can't be sure that another application hasn't already created a registry at that port?

Comment: Your first comment doesn't make sense. The `BindException` means there was already another Registry running, in another JVM, and the subsequent `ClassNotFoundException` means that that Registry didn't have the same CLASSPATH as your JVM. If you don't get the `BindException` you won't get the `ClassNotFoundException` either.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the comment about the empty catch and thought you meant the exception tells me if the registry has a different classpath. The thing is, my application has to run in multiple processes concurrently on the same host (each running under a different user account to interact with a legacy system), so I expect the exception to be thrown most of the time, which is why I didn't pay attention to it. In this (admittedly hacky) setup I get (and ignore) the BindException because I assume another process with the same classpath created the registry. Thanks for clearing things up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was some other Java process running which seemed to interfer with the registry binding. I don't know what this rogue process did exactly but killing it resolved the error. No security manager is needed and simply running the jar as usual works now.